# Terminal emulator that lets me open multiple tiled panes and run specific commands in one line.

Tags: terminal-emulator

On the current project I'm working on  when I start I end up doing something like this:

```
[open terminal]
cd ~/my-project 
npm start

[open terminal ]
cd ~/my-project
firebase serve --only functions

[open terminal]
cd ~/a-dependency 
npm start

[open terminal] 
cd ~/my-project 
[will do git commands here]
```

It's a bit of a pain.

What I'd like to do is have a single command I can run to do all of these things, and start a tiled terminal emulator (like Terminator) running all of these commands. It's important to have them all on separate tiles/windows - so I can see the console output of each of them.

Comment: When speaking of terminal, Is the conclusion that this is meant for Linux correct? Also: must it be free/open-source, or are commercial solutions acceptable as well (and up to which price)?

Comment: Many terminals can do this I can, but an alternative could be to use `screen` or `tmux` that natively multiplexes things.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to launch each as a process *or to have a script that does it for you*.

So, as long as you don't need to see the outputs:

```
[open terminal]
cd ~/my-project 
npm start &
cd ~/my-project
firebase serve --only functions &
cd ~/a-dependency 
npm start &
cd ~/my-project 
<do your git commands>
```

Of course you will need to slay/kill the launched processes when you no longer need them.

Comment: Your answer points out both reasons why I don't want to do this - I can't see the output of the proceses, and have to find and kill them.